# Python 3 invalid syntax with print()

Tags: python-3.x

I've converted a code written in Python 2.6 into Python 3 using 2to3.
All the syntax changes have been made accordingly,
but I still get an error like following:

```
print('Type: ' + t)
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

this happens not only with print() but other totally valid codes like
self.type(arg)

What could be wrong?
I'm using python 3.2 by the way.

Please hlep me out..

Comment: indentations are completely correct as well

Comment: Often mysterious syntax errors are the result of an error above -- like a missing ) -- which is only being *reported* when the first line is found which becomes invalid python.  Look at the prior code.  [BTW, please cut and paste *exactly* the error message.  It should be 'SyntaxError', not 'Syntax Error', so you must've retyped it or edited it afterwards.]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The syntax error is likely on the row above. Looks like a missing parenthesis or something.

Answer (score 0):

Just to demonstrate what the accepted answer is saying,

```
print('Type: ' + "1")
```

gives,

```
Type: 1
```

Answer (score -2):

This is true syntax.

```
print('Type:%d'%t)
```

Comment: Only if `t` is an integer.  What reason do you have to believe it is?